# Convert networkditector class component to fucnction components reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Here I am trying to check the internet is connected or not. If the internet is connected, it does not show any message but if the internet connection is lost it shows an error message.

Please convert below code into react functional component

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './NetworkDetector.css';

export default function (ComposedComponent) {
  class NetworkDetector extends Component {
    state = {
      isDisconnected: false
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.handleConnectionChange();
      window.addEventListener('online', this.handleConnectionChange);
      window.addEventListener('offline', this.handleConnectionChange);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      window.removeEventListener('online', this.handleConnectionChange);
      window.removeEventListener('offline', this.handleConnectionChange);
    }


    handleConnectionChange = () => {
      const condition = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
      if (condition === 'online') {
        const webPing = setInterval(
          () => {
            fetch('//google.com', {
              mode: 'no-cors',
              })
            .then(() => {
              this.setState({ isDisconnected: false }, () => {
                return clearInterval(webPing)
              });
            }).catch(() => this.setState({ isDisconnected: true }) )
          }, 2000);
        return;
      }

      return this.setState({ isDisconnected: true });
    }

    render() {
      const { isDisconnected } = this.state;
      return (
        <div>
          { isDisconnected && (<div className="internet-error">
              <p>Internet connection lost!</p>
            </div>)
          }
          <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  return NetworkDetector;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use react hooks (`useEffect` and `useState`) to convert lifecycle methods and state management in class component.

Try like below

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./NetworkDetector.css";

export default function(ComposedComponent) {
    const NetworkDetector = (props) => {
        const [isDisconnected, setIsDisconnected] = useState(false);

        useEffect(() => {
            handleConnectionChange();
            window.addEventListener("online", handleConnectionChange);
            window.addEventListener("offline", handleConnectionChange);
            return () => {
                window.removeEventListener(
                    "online",
                    handleConnectionChange
                );
                window.removeEventListener(
                    "offline",
                    handleConnectionChange
                );
            };
        }, []);

        const handleConnectionChange = () => {
            const condition = navigator.onLine ? "online" : "offline";
            if (condition === "online") {
                const webPing = setInterval(() => {
                    fetch("//google.com", {
                        mode: "no-cors"
                    })
                        .then(() => {
                            setIsDisconnected(false);
                            clearInterval(webPing);
                        })
                        .catch(() => setIsDisconnected(true));
                }, 2000);
                return;
            }

            return setIsDisconnected(true);
        };

        return (
            <div>
                {isDisconnected && (
                    <div className="internet-error">
                        <p>Internet connection lost!</p>
                    </div>
                )}
                <ComposedComponent {...props} />
            </div>
        );
    };

    return NetworkDetector;
}
```

Comment: @Kamlesh Yaadav, check this out !!

Comment: thank you, sir. but I want to know what is the use of `ComposedComponent`. Please help me out

Comment: it is not working when I wrapped the App component like this-`export default  NetworkDetector(App);`

Comment: I corrected how props  passed, can you check again? This is a higher-order component https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html. `ComposedComponent` is the input to the HoC which will add another sibling div on top of it to show network availability.

Comment: Now it is working but showing a warning on the console.  index.js:1 Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().

Comment: there were a few lines left I removed them. please check again?