# How to detect if internet connection is online again and alert something

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, internet-connection

I am using **navigator.online** to check if internet is offline or online (I know its downside but still its relevant to my project), how can I alert a message "Internet is back" and perform some actions as soon as internt comes again

Answer (score 0):

You could use the online or offline event.
[Resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/Online_and_offline_events#online_and_offline_events)

```
window.addEventListener("online", () => {});
window.addEventListener("offline", () => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this solution, converted to JS (original post link :https://stackoverflow.com/a/70737477/6696948)

```js
    window.isDisconnected = false;
    
    function setIsDisconnected(val) {
      window.isDisconnected = val;
      document.body.textContent = !window.isDisconnected ? "online" : "offline"
    }
    function init() {
      handleConnectionChange();
      window.addEventListener("online", handleConnectionChange);
      window.addEventListener("offline", handleConnectionChange);
      function handleConnectionChange() {
        const condition = navigator.onLine ? "online" : "offline";
        if (condition === "online") {
          const webPing = setInterval(() => {
            fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", {
              mode: "no-cors"
            })
              .then(() => {
                setIsDisconnected(false);
                clearInterval(webPing);
              })
              .catch(() => setIsDisconnected(true));
          }, 2000);
          return;
        }
        setIsDisconnected(true);
      }
    };
 
    init()
```